# What happens if the text editor I paste e.g. passwords in, sends everything to the developer?

Tags: malware, password-management

I run an OpenVPN server at my home for purely personal use. To manage e.g. private keys and passwords, I sometimes paste them into a text editor. The content, if an adversary gets it, would be enough to connect to my VPN server.

Should I worry about the possibility that my text editor sends everything I type in it to the developer?

In my case, I use the open source editor Atom with a couple of packages, also open source. I guess one possibility is to review the source code, but I'm not that good of a programmer. Others may have reviewed the code of Atom, but maybe not checked out all packages as carefully? (Not trying to accuse Atom here, it just happened to be the editor I use.).

Taking a step back, even if the editor can be trusted, what if another program sends my information? Or the OS itself?

Or is the concern outlined here not of much priority compared to other threats?

Comment: Why do you think that text editor would send your  data? There was some speculation that windows does it, but it sends only statistics and not whole memory dumps. On the other hand, antivirus software can send the whole file for analysis if it's suspicious, or it's interesting in other way to them, like it is the case with kaspersky antivirus for example.

Comment: If you can't trust your OS, then you're screwed.

Answer (score 3):

Much of the phishing spam you receive is a link to malware that is attempting to install a malicious key logger on your computers.  Key logging is a highly profitable way to steal credentials, passwords, credit card numbers, etc., so the thieves are highly motivated to do this.

Can an attacker to create a malicious plug-in for your favorite editor that would perform some trivial but useful function, acting as a Trojan Horse, but underneath serving as a key logger?  That's not only possible, it's the bread-and-butter of typical attackers.  It seems the trick would be getting developers to install it, and finding a way to hide the malware and traffic so these tech-savvy users are unaware that their keystrokes are being recorded; however, people are people, and anyone can get phished.

Your question is if this is likely.  In the last few years there has been an increase in attackers attempting to break into code repositories, with the intent to implant malware hooks directly into application source code.  [Krebs has at least one story that hints at this.](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2017/03/payments-giant-verifone-investigating-breach/)  There is no reason to think this avenue of attack isn't still being explored.

So the standard advice applies to editor plugins as much as to any other application you might download: don't install software from untrustworthy repositories; don't fall for phishing attacks; compare the checksums before installing, etc.

Is the editor itself betraying you?  Again, make sure your editor came from an official repository or web site, and not simply from the first random link from google.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you trust your text editor less than the OpenVPN server or the underlying OS? These might be compromised or somehow controlled by the attacker too. Or they might have bugs which can be exploited by an attacker. And the hardware could be compromised too - your keyboard might come with a builtin key logger and your monitor might send its content to your enemies.

Essentially it boils down to the question where do you get your software and hardware from and how much do you trust these sources in terms of building a sufficiently secure product without explicit or implicit backdoors. And of course how much  you trust your friends and family which might have access to your hardware while you are away and which could also add backdoors to your systems.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not worry about "*the possibility that my text editor sends everything I type*", if that text editor is atom. Can you imagine the scandal? You'd hear about it if it were doing such things. There's no way to hide such activity, so someone would scream it from mountaintop if there's a problem.

The plugins might be less reputable, but even there i think open source is self-policing. If the plugins are half-way popular, someone would notice such a blatantly awful (and likely illegal) activity. If you're running actual official copies (did you check the hashes?).

I'm not saying "never", but I strongly agree that "*the concern outlined here (is) not of much priority compared to other threats*".